# Is there any way to make two pages per sheet (landscape) and the page numbering appears as if each column was a page?

Tags: spacing, numbering, columns, geometry, landscape

I want to make a landscape sheet with two pages (like two columns) and I want that the page numbering to be a number per page (a number per column) instead of a number per sheet.

I use `\usepackage[landscape, twocolumn]{geometry}` but I want the page number to appear as if each column was a page.

Is there any way to do that?

And is there any form to make the space between the columns wider?

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SX! The `multicol` package does something like that, albeit I'm not sure how it works over multiple pages.

Comment: How would you manage references, which could include a page reference? Or is this of no concern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A rudimentary approach to this would be to use [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) to set the page number of the left and right column using `\lfoot` and `\rfoot` respectively. The following MWE does exactly that:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape,twocolumn]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{fancyhdr,lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\lfoot{\makebox[\columnwidth]{\thepage}}
\rfoot{\makebox[\columnwidth]{\number\numexpr\value{page}+1}\stepcounter{page}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

The right-hand column "page number" is calculated, and also steps the `page` counter to avoid duplication on subsequent pages. One problem might be that there will *always* be two "page numbers" on a page. Another issue inherent to this approach would be the use of page references, which will be incorrect.

---

The separation between columns is set by the length `\columnsep`, which you can change using

```
\setlength{\columnsep}{<len>}
```

where you specify `<len>`.

Comment: Thank you! Great Solution! The only problem I have is that the numbering starts only on the second sheet when I use \chapter{}. How can I solve the problem ? Thanks.

Comment: @Xpucto: That's because `\chapter`s are usually set using `\thispagestyle{plain}`, which is different from the `fancy` page style. You can either create your own first-page-of-chapter style (since you probably don't want the headline), or set them to be the same (`\makeatletter\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy\makeatother`). Also see section **7 Redefining `plain` style** (p 7) of the [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf).